# Trouble getting AUCTeX to load with emacs update

Tags: emacs, auctex

I have just updated to Gnu Emacs 24 and am having trouble getting AUCTeX working.  I have used the Emacs package manager to install AUCTeX 11.89, and I have `(require 'tex-site)` in my `.emacs` file.  But when `.emacs` is loaded I get the error message: `"File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, tex-site"`

What am I missing?

Comment: If you install it with the package manager (ELPA repository) you may not use `(requite 'tex-site)` in your `.emacs`. try to remove this part and see if AUCTeX is loaded by default

Comment: @RomainPicot I have removed (require 'tex-site) from .emacs.  I think that AUCTeX is working now since C-c C-c works.  But then I get the error message: AUCTeX cannot find a working TeX distribution.  As suggested in the error message, I added /Library/TeX/texbin to my PATH (and also /usr/local/texlive for good mesasure) but I still get the same error message about AUCTeX not being able to find a working TeX distribution.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't understand why, or how, you made the edits that you did to my original question.

Comment: @Ruby: Usually, filenames should be marked up. I can rollback, if you prefer -- there you are

Comment: @Ruby Terminal output, file names, _etc._ are marked as code: it's the standard mark-up on the site.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I didn't know how to markup without having a line break.  (BTW, I'm very happy for experienced SE users to edit my questions to make them cohere with TeX SE standards.)

Comment: @JosephWright: I also don't know how to add mark-up in a comment.

Comment: @Ruby http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Romain Picot said, when AUCTeX is installed with the Emacs Package manager, `.emacs` should not contain `"(require 'tex-site)"`.  I also needed to add `/usr/texbin` to my PATH in my `.emacs` file:

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/texbin"))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/texbin")))
```